# Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit

Tags: rhythmbox

Is there anyway to get Rhythmbox to stop playing the current track when it closes without first pausing/stopping the song manually?

Comment: I recommend just nixing the program until it's made to function reasonably. There are more appropriately set up alternatives. I gather that's the best way to vote in Ubuntu.

Comment: Whenever something is playing music there should be something visible on the screen to pause, stop, and control volume. I played a file and picked one. Rhythmbox. No way to pause or stop was visible. I had to find this question and wander through multiple apps and tabs and dropdowns to find an on/off button hidden away. That makes this program a menace to me. No better than random ads that play music on a browser.

Comment: `sudo apt purge rhythmbox` solves the bug.

Comment: FWIW `sudo apt install clementine` fills my needs and closes when ordered to.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is intentionally the default behaviour: allowing you to minimise ("close") Rhythmbox and control it from the Sound menu.

To work around this you need to "quit" Rhythmbox by selecting File->Quit in the menu, or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

---

Related Question:

- [Is there a plugin for Rhythmbox to exit on close?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454177/is-there-a-plugin-for-rhythmbox-to-exit-on-close)

Comment: Right-click on the launcher Icon and selecting Quit doesn't really quit. That's stupid. Plus, there is no icon in the status bar saying it's running. I have to re-open it and manually go File > Quit

Comment: I'm running Rhythmbox 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and there is no File -> Quit nor will it close with `Ctrl`+`Q`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 as of today, i have to do: killall -9 rhythmbox

Comment: @anjan on *Ubuntu 14.04* you can close it with *Ctrl+W*

Comment: To be clear for people like me who are new to Ubuntu: once the Rhythmbox window is closed, the controls for it are accessed by clicking the loudspeaker icon in the top right hand corner.

Comment: I actually guessed that I could control it from the speaker icon on top, but NO. When I clicked it, it showed only SMPlayer and VLC, even though Rhythmbox was playing and the other two were not even running. I had no other way but to rerun RhythmBox and stop the song there. Is this a bug? Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: This is plain wrong interaction design. The *Quit* action does not quit. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: When it's playing and I have clicked quit, there is no way to control the player except by opening it again. I don't have anything in my sound menu whatsoever except the system volume button (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: 12 years later and this is still a problem. the only way to stop the music is to re-open Rythymbox.

Comment: Crazy this has never been addressed.  Absolutely terrible UI design and default behavior.  In Ubuntu 22.04 I have no sound options in the toolbar other than a global volume.  And right click -> menu -> close does not stop the music.  In Ubuntu 22.04, the entire menu UI is horrendous.

Comment: I uninstalled rythmbox, and it still playing lol. Had to kill the process. What an awful program, and I can't believe Ubuntu ships with it. I'm going to make my own

Answer (score 7):

**Command-line Way**

Try this command on terminal to close `rhythmbox` immediately,

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | awk '$11=="rhythmbox"{print $2}')
```

It's an one way of killing `rhythmbox` using it's process id(pid).

Comment: thanks, do you have such an experience ? I close that but, not work?

Comment: yep, you could pause the mp3 before closing it.

Comment: Killing by pid doesn't work - it simply catches the kill and restarts with a new pid. If it has already been closed, then restart it (e.g. from a terminal), stop the play and then File -> Close

Comment: Or use `pkill rhythmbox`

Comment: @user297009 If rhythmbox is catching the kill, you could `kill -9` it (that's an extreme measure that offers the program no recourse).  Or, it may have a separate program running that starts it again on death, in which case you'd need to kill that program.

Comment: followed by `sudo apt remove rhythmbox`

Comment: Ridiculous command when a simple `pkill rhythmbox`, as pointed out by @lakshayg, does it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is much disagreement and flip/flopping on how the close-window, (x) button, etc. does/should work in Rhythmbox.  In fact both behaviors have been reported as bugs on several occasions for various reasons.  [This one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/658590) claims `close == hide`, while [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/694860) claims `close == quit`.  Whatever the case, I think the functionality should be configurable so it's up to the user to change it.

After reading around through bug reports, I think that's exactly how it's *supposed* to work.  If you read [this comment in the above-mentioned bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/694860/comments/6), the poster claims the behavior can be turned on/off by enabling/disabling the **Status Icon** plugin:

> 1. open Rhythmbox
> 2. Edit > Plugins
> 3. scroll to the end of the list and find the entry marked "Status Icon"
> 4. deselect "Status Icon"
> 5. close the window

I tried this on my system (Ubuntu v10.10, Rhythmbox v0.13.1) and it did not work.  Back wading through the bug reports it seems there was a patch applied to fix an indicator-application compatibly issue that broke the Status Icon plugin behavior.  I am no longer 100% sure what the current status is on all this, but I think the above procedure *should* work.

Indeed, toggling this behavior in Banshee is a very similar process, which actually works.

Answer (score 3):

With some applications, typically media players, they run in the background unless you quit the application. Whenever it is open, use File > Quit or Ctrt+Q. They typically run in indicators on your panel. This is so that instead of closing when you want to clean your desktop, they keep playing.

Comment: In Rhythmbox we use "Music/Quit" instead of "File/Quit".

Comment: Oops! You are correct good sir! In fact, my own player Clementine uses that too! I should probably start looking before I post....

Answer (score 3):

I know that Clementine and Audacious stop playing when you hit the "x" button. Maybe you should try those players instead.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the sound icon in the top bar and stop / pause from there (under volume control you have player control) , or close it while window visible from the file menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is still not fixed in Ubuntu 20.04, and there are several bug reports about it, among which the ones previously mentioned here, and also [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1754125).

The simple way to stop it is

```
pkill rhythmbox
```

Or you can restart it, and select "Stop & Quit" in the menu.

After that, I definitely solved the problem with

```
sudo apt purge rhythmbox
```

:-)