# Why doesn't Rhythmbox just quit when I close the widow?

Tags: sound, multimedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit)

It seems to me if one completely closes the window of an application, that application should cease. However, this does not seem to be the case with Rhythmbox. Why?