# Can I get transmission to quit instead of minimize?

Tags: transmission

Transmission has this incredibly aggravating tendency to not stop when I click the exit button.

Instead, it minimizes. When I click to exit, I want the program to cease immediately, but I can't figure out how to do so via the preference menus.  Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: Same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit/

Comment: I did not see that question, but what about for transmission?

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop` ? >:)

Comment: also could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/977132

Comment: @Rinzwind what will stopping that do?  Will I need to run that every time i want to close transmission?

Comment: It will stop transmission for sure ;)

Comment: Since we have a q+a for rhythmbox I edited this question to be just about transmission.

Comment: @Rinzwind that really doesn't answer anything...what does that command do?

Comment: @acolyte it does exactly what it says? stop transmission...

Comment: @Rinzwind Does it change the behavior of clicking the exit button?

Comment: @Rinzwind: I just searched around for `transmission-daemon`. I think this is different from what we get in standard Ubuntu install (although made by the same developers). So, stopping the daemon wouldn't work in this case since it isn't running in the first place (most probably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Transmission:

Disable the checkbox beside *Show Transmission icon in the notification area*. You would find this option under *Edit* Menu → *Preferences* → *Desktop* Tab.

[image: transmission]

Comment: So is it possible to disable this pointless "intelligent" quitting?  If i click "exit", I want the thing to stop, not keep going.  If i anted it to continue running, I wouldn't have clicked "exit".  Thanks for the Transmission info, though.  I'll try that out when I get home tonight.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to quit Rhythmbox in the way you desire (although I think the way it decides to quit or not makes much more sense). If I were in your position and desired the functionality to actually close the application I would have used another music application - vlc, banshee, etc and made them the default for music.

Comment: Funny, I came here searching for the exact opposite thing, shouting “who makes these things, don't they know that users expect these things to run in the background normally unless explicitly closed from the tray”. Looks like it's off by default now, but you can never please 'em all!