# How to add Rhythmbox controls to sound menu in Gnome-Shell?

Tags: rhythmbox, music

I noticed that i cannot close rhythmbox by clicking close from the window. Checked this thread : Checked this thread [Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit?lq=1) and tried disabling related plugins but this didnot solve this problem. Then i wanted to stop music from the sound menu on the panel. But when on Gnome, sound menu on the panel does not have rhythmbox shortcuts while on Ubuntu or ubuntu 2d it has. How can i add rhythmbox to sound menu?

Comment: Check this link . This might help you.


 http://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit

Answer (score 4):

In gnome-shell it is only available thru an extension. like all extensions whether they work for you would depend on what version of gnome-shell you have & is the extension compatible (or can you make it compatible

So search for extensions...[image]

Ex. this one works fine in 13.10, may not in 12.04 (though it's appears to only be active when player is 'active', ie. it can't be used to start player

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/

Comment: Confirmed working on 12.04. Thank you that's exactly what i was looking for.