# Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit - still

Tags: rhythmbox

Also still not solved in Ubuntu 23.04.
Rhythmbox 3.4.6.
I would like the music to stop when the window is closed. Unfortunately, I can't take part in this question due to a lack of reputation. Questionable system.

[Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found is a plugin that was last edited in 2014 but still works:
https://github.com/fossfreedom/close-on-hide/tree/master
I copied the files:

- close-on-hide.plugin
- close-on-hide.py

to `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins`
Then activate the plugin in Rhythmbox and problem solved.